# Read geoip data from database or binary file. Which is faster?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, geolitecity

I need to use the geoip data files from Maxmind and I want to know which is faster:

- Import CSV into a mysql database (about 60 Mb) and query it
- Use the binary .DAT files (18 Mb) and the corresponding PHP API

Comment: did you run a benchmark?

Comment: I only tried the MySQL alternative, which is quite slow. Testing the .DAT + API option now. I hoped somebody already found the best one

Comment: php.net generally speaks about getting it from a dat file so I would assume that. Though it depends where you want to run it, what the storage/memory/cache is like on each? I assume you want to know which is faster because you expect much of a difference between them?
If speed is your thing you could offload the GEOIP'ing to varnish or something also.